# Unique fields on mySQL table - generating promo codes

Tags: mysql

I am developing a PHP script and I have a table like this:

```
TABLE_CODE
   code  varchar  8
   name  varchar  30
```

this code column has to be a code using random letters from A to Z and characters from 0 to 9 and has to be unique. all uppercase. Something like

```
A4RTX33Z
```

I have create a method to generate this code using PHP. But this is a intensive task because I have to query the database to see if the generated code is unique before proceeding and the table may have a lot of records.

Because I know mySQL is a bag of tricks but not having advanced knowledge about it now, I wonder if there's some mechanism that could be built in a table to run a script (or something) every time a new record in created on that table to fill the code column with a unique value.

thanks

---

edit: What I wonder is if there's a way to created the code on-the-fly, as the record is being added to the table and that code being unique.

Comment: Why you want to use totally random `code` field like this?

Comment: because this will be codes used to identify certain elements in a promotion for a given user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better generate these codes in SQL. This is 8-character random "Promo code generator":

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 
TABLE_CODE(name, code)
VALUES(
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 8)), -- random 8 characters fixed length
    'your code name'
)
```

Add `UNIQUE` on `code` field as @JW suggested, and some error-handling in PHP, because sometimes generated value may be not `UNIQUE`, and MySQL will raise error in that situation.

Comment: But this requires checking if the random value already exists.

Comment: What happens if code is UNIQUE and the generated code already exists?

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper i added info about "already exists". Are you using PDO or mysqli in PHP?

Comment: See @Jack answer and put my SQL there. This will be complete answer :)

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper As a side note, if you let SQL generate the code you will still need PHP (or stored procedure) to handle the case where it already exists; on top of that, you won't have access to the generated code inside PHP, which may cause problems later if you need to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a UNIQUE constraint on the code column is the first thing you would need to do. Then, to insert the code I would write a small loop like this:

```
// INSERT IGNORE will not generate an error if the code already exists
// rather, the affected rows will be 0.
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO table_code (code, name) VALUES (?, ?)');
$name = 'whatever name';
do {
    $code = func_to_generate_code();
    $stmt->execute(array($code, $name));
} while (!$stmt->rowCount()); // repeat until at least one row affected
```

As the table grows the number of loops may increase, so if you feel it should only try three times, you could add it as a loop condition and throw an error if that happens.

Btw, I would suggest using transactions to make sure if an error occurs after the code generation, rolling back will make sure the code is removed (can be reused).

Comment: you can use my SQL in your answer. It will be complete solution.

Comment: @Kamil Not really, because if the code is generated in PHP it can be used later; but if the code is generated in MySQL there would be no way of knowing the code other than querying the database again.